# Windows Server Firewall: Block all incoming traffic except from domain members

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, tcp, udp

I want to secure a Remote-Desktop server farm (running on Windows Server 2019). I run multiple servers with different roles (as Active Directory, Connection Broker, RD Gateway, ...).

Now I want to setup the firewall so that only the 443 port of the RD Gateway is available from the internet. All other servers should be unavailable.

My idea was to create a firewall rule, that blocks all incoming traffic except from the computers, which are members of the domain - but I don't know how to realize that.

Things I DONT want:

- Allow all incoming traffic from the domain members - the default windows firewall rules should persist
- Manually specify all IP addresses which should be allowed to access the servers
- Delete all preset firewall rules and set all rules manually per protocol, port and IP

I hope you can help me out with this.

Comment: You should be creating the firewall rule to restrict traffic from the Internet on your Internet-facing firewall appliance. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes this is exactly the thing I’m trying to do. It’s a virtualized cloud server - not supporting a private network interface or vSwitch. I’m able to mange the server with a VNC console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IPv4 there is an easy solution : Add firewall rules that block all
incoming connections from any IP address range that is not in your segment.

You may need to add two rules for the ranges.
One for `1.1.1.1` up to your IP segment,
and another for the IP following your segment and up to the end of the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to leverage that functionality of the Windows Firewall is to implement [Domain/Server Isolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-deployment-guide). Both the Server and connecting client will need to be configured to use the same `Main Mode Rule` and `Connection Security Rule`. This allows them to negotiate an IPsec channel and achieve Domain Member authentication. These rules should be distributed via GPO or administrative script.

If there will be off-site clients connecting, they will also need access to a domain controller. For example, first connect to the company VPN before allowing access to the RDP server. This is to achieve the authentication/authorization of IPsec. To get around this use a Preshared Key for the Main Mode rule.

Taking this route is nothing short of complex though the result is a far more secure infrastructure.